# Entity Specific Listner/Event/Interceptor in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having many entities (more than 1000) but i need listener/interceptor/event for specific entities (70-80). I don't want to check based on the if else condition in the interceptor because  makes code dirty .

Is there any annotation or interface in spring / Hibernate that does listens  only for that annotation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a marker interface (no methods) and add it to all the entities.

In the interceptor's method just check

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
    Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
    throws CallbackException {

    System.out.println("onSave");

    if (entity instanceof IMarkerInterface){
        doSomethingWith(entity);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you can add a custom annotation for the entities and use `entity.getClass().getClass().getAnnotation(MarkerAnnotation.class)`. Just check whether the annotation exists and apply your logic accordingly.